# Salesforce Lightning - Summary level formula to compute rate of installed voicemails out of eligible voicemails

Tags: lightning, reporting, formula-field, report-formula

I have just started learning how to write row-level formulas on Salesforce Lightning.
I am attempting to create a summary formula column while only being eligible to use at most 1 row-level formula in a report.

The purpose is to have the summary formula column output the percentage of voicemails installed out of eligible voicemails. As of right now I have only been able to have the summary formula column display the number of voicemails installed, without accounting for not eligible voicemails.

This is my current formula code:

[Row level formula] *# voicemail OK* :

> IF(TEXT(Onboarding__c.ContactAccountRelation__c.VoicemailStatus__c)="Voicemail Installed Correctly", 1, 0)

[Summary formula column] *# voicemails validated* :

> (CDF1:SUM/RowCount)*100

This displays the percentage of voicemails installed without accounting that some voicemails are impossible to install, and should therefore be removed from this rate computation. The "uninstallable voicemails" are labeled as "Uninstallable" in the feature VoicemailStatus. If I could add 1 more row-level formula I would compute the number of uninstallable voicemails and then I would update my summary level formula as follows

> (CDF1:SUM/(RowCount-CDF2:SUM))*100

How can I express the ratio I want to express in my summary level formula without going over the Salesforce Lightning's limit of 1 row-level formula per report?

Thank you. Please don't hesitate to suggest helpful resources to learn more about Salesforce Lightning row-level formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Try using report filters to exclude all rows where `[VoicemailStatus]=="Uninstallable"`.

Now all rows in the report are strictly voicemails that can be installed and your summary formula should reflect the true percentage you are loooking to show (% voicemails installed out of all possible voicemail installations).